# not able to get part of response array value using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, quartz

```
<s:property value="triggers"/> 

response:
 [
    Trigger 'PSP_Functional_METRS_Trigger_Group.METRS_Document_Events_Generator_JMS': triggerClass: 'org.quartz.CronTrigger isVolatile: false calendar: '
    null ' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Mon Oct 10 11:00:00 PDT 2022,
    Trigger 'PSP_RDC_Group.RDC_Mapper_Trigger': triggerClass: 'org.quartz.CronTrigger isVolatile: false calendar: '
    null ' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Mon Oct 10 10:52:00 PDT 2022, 
    Trigger 'JobInitializationPlugin.JobInitializationPlugin_jobInitializer_jobs-letter_xml': triggerClass: 'org.quartz.SimpleTrigger isVolatile: true calendar: '
    null ' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Mon Oct 10 11:05:31 PDT 2022,
    Trigger 'PSP_Letters_Group.MDCL0147_Mapper_Trigger': triggerClass: 'org.quartz.CronTrigger isVolatile: false calendar: '
    null ' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Mon Oct 10 12:02:00 PDT 2022,
    ]
```

I want the value : org.quartz.CronTrigger which is triggerClass Attribute from this responseArray.

I tried it by coding:

```
<s:iterator value="triggers" status="stat">
                    <s:iterator>
                      Key:<s:property value="key"/>
                   <br>
                    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

output is :

```
Key:PSP_Functional_METRS_Trigger_Group.METRS_Document_Events_Generator_JMS
Key:PSP_RDC_Group.RDC_Mapper_Trigger
Key:JobInitializationPlugin.JobInitializationPlugin_jobInitializer_jobs-letter_xml
```

I want to know how can I get the value:
for trigger Class from the response.

Comment: Not knowing what's in the collection it's hard to say.

Comment: it is the response I got after sending the request, and trying to display it using <s:property value="triggers"/>

Comment: Not knowing what's in the response you get after sending the request it's hard to say.